# How to send post request to an HTML form in parse cloud code (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, http-post, html-parsing, forms, parse-cloud-code

i want to get data from that website :

http://95.0.153.145/GelenDocView/PlanliKesintilerList.aspx

in that website, you choose a city, start date and end date. then website shows which towns in the city have electricity problems between that dates. i want to get that data and save in my parse class.

in cloud code, i wrote that function :

```
Parse.Cloud.define("Uedas", function(request, response) {
   var cheerio = require('cloud/modules/cheerio.js');
   var myfunctions = require('cloud/modules/myfunctions.js');

   Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({

           // send post request that <form name="frmPlanliKesinti" >                               
           method: 'POST',
           url: 'http://95.0.153.145/GelenDocView/PlanliKesintilerList.aspx',

           body: {
               ddlIl : '22',
               txtBaslangicTarihi : '01.12.2015',
               txtBitisTarihi : '31/01/2016'
           }

    }).then(function(httpResponse) {
              // success
              $ = cheerio.load(httpResponse.text);
              var list = $('td').map(function() {
                                        return $(this).text();
                                        }).get();

              response.success(list.toString());

    },function(httpResponse) {
              // error
             response.error("http request error : " + httpResponse.status);
      });

});
```

but that function returns http request error 500. how can i fix it and get data?

Comment: check server side error logs

Comment: i found that web sites uses SOAP request. But i do not know how to make a soap request in parse cloud code:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951384/soap-request-in-parse-cloud-code